# Creating a plot with a non-linear X-scale, Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to create a plot using the values 10^0 10^3 10^6 10^9... on the x-axis. Matlab does not automatically rescale so my values are all down in the left corner.

My current code is:

```
figure('name','My plot title');
hold on
plot(kap, reg, '--mo');
plot(kap, reij, '-.r*');
hold off
```

kap is a vector of x values -> 10^0 10^3 10^6 10^9.....,
reg and reij are measurements.

---

### Maybe loglog, semilogx could help?

A picture of my plot: [enter link description here](http://www.bilddump.se/bilder/20140410055150-31.208.41.252.png)

---

The problem was that I should use loglog or semilogx and not use it in a figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, `semilogx` is what you want:

```
semilogx(kap,reg,'--mo');
```

`loglog` gives logarithmic scales for both `x` and `y` axes, and `semilogy` plots with a lagarithmic scale on the y axis.

```
x=10.^(0:3:30);
y=rand(size(x));
semilogx(x,y)
```

Comment: It was not that simple unfortunately. The x axis scale is now 0, 1, 2, 3..... times 10^14 :S and all my measurements except one is in the bottom left corner. I need to adjust the scale in another way

Comment: What is the range of `kap`?

Comment: kap=[10^0, 10^3, 10^6, 10^9, 10^12, 10^15]

Comment: I put another example in my answer, how do your results differ?

Comment: If i use that its not may values anymore?:S

Comment: It's just a test! I can't see why your data isn't evenly spread along the `x` axis. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: thank you any way, I will play around with your code and give you the right answer if it helps me:) I would vote for you if I had the rep